# Creating an aws-ec2 instance using jclouds API

Tags: java, jclouds

I am trying to create an aws-ec2 instance using `jclouds`. While executing the code I am getting the exception below

> "java.util.NoSuchElementException: key [aws-ec2] not in the list of providers or apis: {}".

How can I resolve this exception?

Comment: this solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33639683/470341

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the aws-ec2-X.X.X.jar on your classpath. To get the jar file you could use a Maven pom.xml like and do a `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory="./lib"`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <properties>
    <jclouds.version>1.7.1</jclouds.version>
  </properties>
  <name>Cloud Portability with Multi-Cloud Toolkits Workshop</name>
  <description>https://github.com/rackerlabs/multi-cloud-workshop/</description>
  <groupId>multi.cloud.workshop</groupId>
  <artifactId>multi-cloud-workshop</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- jclouds Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Cloud Provider Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-ec2</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>hpcloud-compute</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>rackspace-cloudservers-us</artifactId>
      <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```